# good practices to extend a class with custom functions in python: when to apply and how to code it?

Tags: python, class, extend

I am not sure if question is posed correctly:

I am working with a library, as an example in this case networkx, and building functions manipulating networkx classes (graphs).

Example:

```
def myfunction( graph, params ):
   # do something
```

For the sake of learning better coding and readability, when does it make sense to extend a graph class so that I can use myfunction as:

```
import networkx

mygraph = networkx.Graph()
mygraph.myfunction(params)  #mygraph is an instance of graph class of networkx 
#myfunction can be applied to all graphs instances of networkx
#without passing graphs as parameter
```

?

A few examples for doing it with comments when would make sense for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

> when does it make sense to extend a ... class?

When the class you are using does not exactly do what you need. But that could be anything, and there's no answer to "anything".

So start with one of the [many tutorials that can be found online](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+classes+oo+tutorial) to get a feeling what classes are or [dig into the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes).

If something does not work, come back to ask another question. Have fun!